# ios-sim showdevicetypes returns empty after Mojave 10.14.4 update

Tags: flutter

As the title says, after updating MacOS to Mojave 10.14.4,
ios-sim showdevicetype returns zero results.

I am using Flutter as the mobile development platform.
I have also re-install ios-sim using

npm install ios-sim -g

but the results the same.

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I just issue the following command:

npm install ios-sim -g

And it works.. but I am not sure why it didn't work much earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced similar issues and after spending multiple hours, this has been worked out for me.

```
flutter run -d com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2
```

If you are using the older build system then you can try with extra flag for Modern build system like this

```
flutter run -d com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2 --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

Updating npm-install, iOS-sim is not going to make any difference.

Let me know if this don't work for you.

Comment: You can also try this solution as well. I haven't tried this as the solution that posted worked for me. Just adding this solution for reference. https://gist.github.com/ZevEisenberg/5a172662cb576872d1ab

Comment: I tried but it does not work for me. I am not using ionic or cordova but Flutter.
Doing this : xcrun simctl erase all 
also did not work :-(

Comment: This:
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService; xcrun simctl list devices | grep "iPhone\|iPad" | awk '{print $(NF -1)}' | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1 | grep -E "^[0-9A-F]{8}-([0-9A-F]{4}-){3}[0-9A-F]{12}$" | xargs -I {} xcrun simctl erase "{}"

did not work too ...

Comment: Didn't realise the flutter part, my bad. Could you try this command -> "flutter run -d com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2"  // Give the version number of simulator installed on your machine

Comment: I used to just do

ios-sim start --devicetypeid iPhone-6-Plus, 11.3

Is there a way to get back the above?

Comment: Not able to find out the way to bring back to that behaviour but will let you know once i will find it. Did above command worked for you?